# Options Pages are only showing after disabling and enabling my Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm the author of a small os vs2015 extension ([AsmDude](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude)) and my users complain that the options pages are only visible after disabling the extension, restarting vs, enabling the extension and restarting vs again.

1. I have sifted through many tutorials, examples and manuals on how to use the ProvideOptionPage attribute properly, but nothing helped.
2. I have run devenv.exe with /LOG, but nothing strange comes up.
3. I have cleaned all registry entries that this plugin makes, but no fix.
4. The problem exists on clean installs of visual studio 2015 (sp2)

Next are some relevant c# code snippets:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("AsmDude", Vsix.Description, Vsix.Version)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.NoSolution)]
[Guid(Guids.GuidPackage_str)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
[ProvideOptionPage(typeof(OptionsPageSyntaxHighlighting), "AsmDude", "Syntax Highlighting", 0, 0, true)]
public sealed class AsmDudePackage : Package { 
//snip
}
[Export(typeof(DialogPage))]
[Guid(Guids.GuidOptionsPageSyntaxHighlighting)]
public class OptionsPageSyntaxHighlighting : DialogPage { 
// snip
}
```

**Question**: how to debug such a vague problem? There must be a warning or error message logged somewhere that could help me pinpoint the problem.

Regards!

**Edit**: this question can also be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4c98a81-d236-4419-98f7-70de058ae8b0) on MSDN.

Comment: The best logging tool for extensions is to enable fusion logging in the registry and looking for anything having issues loading. Good luck, nasty issue there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx